# Ruby: Insert Multiple Values Into String

Tags: ruby, string

Suppose we have the string `"aaabbbccc"` and want to use the `String#insert` to convert the string to `"aaa<strong>bbb</strong>ccc"`. Is this the best way to insert multiple values into a Ruby string using `String#insert` or can multiple values simultaneously be added:

```
string = "aaabbbccc"
opening_tag = '<strong>'
opening_index = 3
closing_tag = '</strong>'
closing_index = 6
string.insert(opening_index, opening_tag)
closing_index = 6 + opening_tag.length # I don't really like this
string.insert(closing_index, closing_tag)
```

Is there a way to simultaneously insert multiple substrings into a Ruby string so the closing tag does not need to be offset by the length of the first substring that is added?  I would like something like this one liner:

```
string.insert(3 => '<strong>', 6 => '</strong>') # => "aaa<strong>bbb</strong>ccc"
```

Comment: Why in the world would you limit yourself to String#insert? Regexes would be much cleaner if it's not specifically index-oriented.

Comment: @syrion - Your question is valid.  I have an aversion to Regex because I don't know it well yet...maybe it's time to learn.

Comment: In this case, it'd make things much easier:  `"aaabbbccc".sub(/(bbb)/, '<strong>\1</strong>')`. Of course, that presumes that you're just replacing the `bbb` specifically, but it can be modified to your needs and even regex is going to be less inscrutable than `String#insert` acrobatics. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's have some fun.  How about

```
class String
  def splice h
    self.each_char.with_index.inject('') do |accum,(c,i)|
      accum + h.fetch(i,'') + c
    end  
  end  
end  

"aaabbbccc".splice(3=>"<strong>", 6=>"</strong>")
=> "aaa<strong>bbb</strong>ccc"
```

(you can encapsulate this however you want, I just like messing with built-ins because Ruby lets me)

Comment: +1 Nice answer. Fyi you can replace `+=` with just `+`.

Comment: @Matt thanks.  The `+=` was a remnant from when I had two lines in the block.

Comment: @roippi awesome answer. But it seems like "aaabbbccc".splice(9=>"</strong>") will not work

Answer (score 1):

How about inserting from right to left?

```
string = "aaabbbccc"
string.insert(6, '</strong>')
string.insert(3, '<strong>')
string # => "aaa<strong>bbb</strong>ccc"
```

Comment: Right to left is certainly a better approach - thanks :)  So does that mean there is no way to insert multiple values simultaneously with Ruby?

Comment: @Powers, I don't know a way to insert multiple values at specific positions. But if your intention is to wrap `bbb` with `<strong>..</strong>`, you can use `String#gsub`: `string.gsub!(/bbb/, '<strong>\0</strong>')`

Answer (score 1):

```
opening_tag = '<strong>'
opening_index = 3
closing_tag = '</strong>'
closing_index = 6

string = "aaabbbccc"
string[opening_index...closing_index] = 
   opening_tag + string[opening_index...closing_index] + closing_tag
#=> "<strong>bbb</strong>"
string
#=> "aaa<strong>bbb</strong>ccc"
```

Comment: Using `string[opening_index...closing_index]`, you don't need to calculate the length.

Answer (score 0):

If your string is comprised of three groups of consecutive characters, and you'd like to insert the opening tag between the first two groups and the closing tag between the last two groups, regardless of the size of each group, you could do that like this:

```
def stuff_tags(str, tag)    
  str.scan(/((.)\2*)/)
    .map(&:first)
    .insert( 1, "<#{tag}>")
    .insert(-2, "<\/#{tag}>")
    .join
end

stuff_tags('aaabbbccc', 'strong')  #=> "aaa<strong>bbb</strong>ccc"
stuff_tags('aabbbbcccccc', 'weak') #=> "aa<weak>bbbb</weak>cccccc"
```

I will explain the regex used by `scan`, but first would like to show how the calculations proceed for the string 'aaabbbccc':

```
a = 'aaabbbccc'.scan(/((.)\2*)/)
  #=> [["aaa", "a"], ["bbb", "b"], ["ccc", "c"]]
b = a.map(&:first)
  #=> ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"] 
c = b.insert( 1, "<strong>")
  #=> ["aaa", "<strong>", "bbb", "ccc"]
d = c.insert(-2, "<\/strong>")
  #=> ["aaa", "<strong>", "bbb", "</strong>", "ccc"]
d.join
  #=> "aaa<strong>bbb</strong>ccc"
```

We need two capture groups in the regex.  The first (having the first left parenthesis) captures the string we want.  The second captures the first character, `(.)`.  This is needed so that we can require that it be followed by zero or more copies of that character, `\2*`.

Here's another way this can be done:

```
def stuff_tags(str, tag)    
  str.chars.chunk {|c| c}
    .map {|_,a| a.join}
    .insert( 1, "<#{tag}>")
    .insert(-2, "<\/#{tag}>")
    .join
end
```

The calculations of `a` and `b` above change to the following:

```
a = 'aaabbbccc'.chars.chunk {|c| c}
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x000001021622d8>:each>
  # a.to_a => [["a",["a","a","a"]],["b",["b","b","b"]],["c",["c","c","c"]]]
b = a.map {|_,a| a.join }
  #=> ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
```